# Leer JSON y obtener respuesta con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo .json con este formato:

```
{
  "filename": "usersInfo",
  "userType": "adminUser",
  "Date": "02/20/2022",
  "type": "countrySample",
  "file_version": "1.0",
  "userInfo": [
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "State": "Texas"
    },
    {
      "country": "Canada",
      "State": "Alberta"
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "State": "California"
    },
    {
      "country": "Canada",
      "State": "British Columbia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Australia",
      "State": "NSW"
    }
  ]
}
```

Quiero juntar listas de estados del mismo país; esta es la respuesta que tengo que obtener:

```
{
  "filename": "usersInfo",
  "userType": "adminUser",
  "Date": "02/20/2022",
  "type": "countrySample",
  "file_version": "1.0",
  "userInfo": [
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "State": [
        "Texas",
        "California"
      ]
    },
    {
      "country": "canada",
      "State": [
        "Alberta",
        "British Columbia"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Country": "Australia",
      "State": [
        "NSW"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

He intentado esto:

```
import json

file_name = 'file1.json'

def read_json_get_country(file_name):
    countries = []
    with open(file_name) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        for row in data['userInfo']:
            if row['country'] not in countries:
                countries.append(row['country'])
    return countries

def read_json(file_name, countries):
    response = {}
    response['State'] = []
    op_dict = dict()
    with open(file_name) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        filename = data['filename']
        userType = data['userType']
        date = data['Date']
        type_ = data['type']
        file_version = data['file_version']
        #response.append({ 'filename': filename, 'userType': userType, 'Date': date, 'type': type_, 'file_version': file_version})
        for row in data['userInfo']:
            for country in countries:
                if country in row['country']:
                    #print(country, row['State'])
                    response['State'].append(row['State'])
    print(response)
            
countries = read_json_get_country(file_name)
read_json(file_name, countries)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El quid de tu requerimiento es como convertir cierto formato que tiene una lista de diccionarios, agrupando por el país, en tu caso, sería `data['userInfo']` y los datos de esta lista son algo así:

```
lista = [
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "State": "Texas"
    },
    {
      "country": "Canada",
      "State": "Alberta"
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "State": "California"
    },
    {
      "country": "Canada",
      "State": "British Columbia"
    },
    {
      "country": "Australia",
      "State": "NSW"
    }
]
```

Lo primero es agrupar por país, y agregar cada estado a una lista del diccionario por país:

```
agrupado = {}
for country, state in [(d['country'], d['State']) for d in lista]:
  if country not in agrupado:
     agrupado[country] = []
  agrupado[country].append(state)
```

Lo que restaría es reacomodar los datos para que respeten el formato esperado:

```
lista_final = []
for k,v in agrupado.items():
  lista_final.append({"country": k, "state": v})

print(lista_final)

[{'country': 'USA', 'state': ['Texas', 'California']}, 
 {'country': 'Canada', 'state': ['Alberta', 'British Columbia']}, 
 {'country': 'Australia', 'state': ['NSW']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
import json
with open(file_name) as file:
    informacion = json.load(file)

# Soluciona lo de la apertura del archivo tal que cargue en memoria y 
# le quede como el ejemplo que propone


countries = {}
for user_info in informacion['userInfo']:
    states = countries.get(user_info['country'])
    if not states:
        states = []
    states.append(user_info['State'])
    countries[user_info['country']] = states

print(countries)
```

Yo lo probé y me da el resultado esperado, le queda algo así:

```
{
   'USA': ['Texas', 'California'], 
   'Canada': ['Alberta', 'British Columbia'], 
   'Australia': ['NSW']
}
```

Obvio puede cambiar los nombres de las variables por algo más representativo y que no gener confusión.

Para que le quede todo con la misma información debe colocarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
data = {}
keys = informacion.keys()
for key in keys:
    if key == 'userInfo':
        data[key] = countries
        continue
    data[key] = informacion[key]

print(data)
```

le queda algo así:

```
{'filename': 'usersInfo', 'userType': 'adminUser', 'Date': '02/20/2022', 'type': 'countrySample', 'file_version': '1.0', 'userInfo': {'USA': ['Texas', 'California'], 'Canada': ['Alberta', 'British Columbia'], 'Australia': ['NSW']}}
```

*(a ver si así me gano los puntos)*

Comment: Como puedo mantener las otras cosas del json? osea mentener el mismo formato del json con los nuevos datos?

Comment: Podés usar [las opciones del codificador](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)